# Django jQuery-File-Upload upload Adding the user_id to the Model

Tags: django

I am using jQuery-File-Upload in Django based on this tutorial:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html

I want to add the User_id to the Model.

This View is using JSON data passed from the html jquery.

Do I modify the json or can I add it in the Model?

Thank you.

MODEL:

```
class Files(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d/")
    created = models.DateTimeField ( auto_now_add = True )
```

VIEW:

```
class BasicUploadView(View):

    def get(self, request):

        file_list = Files.objects.all()

        content = {
            'files': file_list            
         }

        return render(self.request, 'upload/index.html', content )


    def post(self, request):

        user_id = request.user.id

        form = UploadForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            file = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': file.file.name, 'url': file.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

FORM:

```
class UploadForm ( forms.ModelForm ):

    class Meta:
        model = Files
        fields = ['file']
```

Comment: Have you made  a `ModelForm` for file upload ??

Comment: good idea. updated.  thanks.

Comment: You can do that in the views itself  by import `usermodel` in django !